# If someone transmits on 151.88 MHz and I listen on 151.18 MHz, how likely would I hear their transmission?

Tags: receiver, baofeng, uv-5r

I have a cheap baofeng uv-5r, and I sometimes hear an intermittent transmission which pulses past the squelch threshold with periods of dead space between, roughly 0.75 seconds or less.

My job uses a repeater and radioreference.com lists the used frequency as 151.18 MHz.

I have trouble hearing them on the baofeng, but not my alinco dj500t, a question I'm sure for a separate post as to why.

Anyways I hear this pulse on both the work frequency and MURS channel 1 (151.88 MHz). Can anyone shed light on this?

In summation of the question, is it possible someone transmitting on a nearby frequency is being picked up?

To add to the final question, it seems to me that listening on 151.00 MHz could potentially monitor the whole 151.**** MHz area, based on the way my alinco functions, of this I'm very unsure, and don't want to seem unintelligent, but I am very new, is that possible?

Comment: wild guess, you mean Megahertz (MHz), not Millihertz (mHz)? I'm going to go ahead and edit your question :)

Comment: also, **never** be ashamed to ask. Asking doesn't make you seem unintelligent – on the contrary, it makes you seem interested and, with the amount of own work you've shown here, rather clever!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible for a strong enough interfering RF signal to overload the front end amplifier(s) of a receiver.  Once overloaded into a non-linear range, all bets are off as to the resulting bandwidth of the interfering signal, which could then splatter into many nearby channels.

If the stop-band attenuation of any of a receiver filters is poor, it's possible for a strong enough signal in a stop-band to blast right through the stop-band, above the squelch or demodulation threshold, and then possibly alias down to a different or image frequency during any heterodyning, digital sampling or processing.

It's also possible for a strong enough interfering RF signal to couple into a receiver's wiring past any RF or IF filtering stages (even directly into the audio amplifier or the DC power supplies), thus potentially turning the receiver into a wide band demodulator of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, this is a question of the bandwidth - or better said of 2 bandwidths.
In practice it's much more complex. But let's have a look at bandwidth theory first:

1. the bandwidth of your transceiver
2. the bandwidth of the signal interfering you.

   - Let's assume you have your receiver on 151,180,000 Hz.
   - Let's further assume your receiver has a bandwidth on FM of 15 kHz.

This means that you will receive signals between 151,180,000 +/- 7.5 kHz which means that whenever a signal is transmitted between 151,172,500 and 151,187,500 you will receive it.

The other part is the transmitting signal:

You also have a bandwidth there. So let's assume you have a signal on 151,880,000 with a bandwidth of 1 MHz (maybe for transmitting digital data). Thus it will interfere between 151,380,000 and 152,380,000 (+/- 500 kHz).

The question is - will you be interfered by this signal on your frequency 151,180?

The answer is: it depends. In theory no, because the interfering bandwidth does not touch your receiver frequency (see above). In practice your receiver is not ideal - and speaking about Baofeng, it's as far from ideal as it can be - by still working more or less.

There are many reasons why even good and expensive receivers have troubles with signals on other frequencies. In a nutshell **it's just a question of the signal strength of the other signal and of the filter quality of the receiver**. Also the frequencies of both signals matter, because they might be mixed up into new frequencies in the reception path of the transceiver. I assume that the signal on 151,88 is very strong.